# Can't seem to change directory - "No such file or directory" error using PuTTY

Tags: unix, putty

I am required to use PuTTY to submit a program but I have never used it before and am having a hard time changing my directory. I am successfully connected to a Linux computer from my own but can't seem to change the directory to where I need it to be. The file I wish to transfer is located here:

```
C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Life
```

I therefore assumed this would work:

```
cd \C:\Users\xxx\workspace\Life
```

However I get the "No such file or directory" response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That would change the directory on the remote server rather than your local machine.  As you have SSH access to the server, try using WinSCP to transfer the file to the remote linux server. (I assume you are on Windows)

Comment: When you have PuTTY, you might just as well use pscp, which is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WinSCP - Free SFTP, SCP and FTP client for Windows](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY is a telnet client. It isn't used for file transfer. I assume you're using the PSFTP, the ftp client that is part of the PuTTY suite.

If that's the case, then to change local directories, use `lcd` instead of `cd`. The `cd` command is for changing directories on the linux computer you are connected to.

EDIT:

The easiest way to transfer files is with FTP. As it turns out, you don't need PuTTY or any other FTP client; Windows has built-in FTP support through Windows Explorer. Just type `ftp://accountname@linuxcomputer.myschool.edu` into the address bar (substituting the correct info, of course). Explorer should ask for a password and after you enter it, you should see the target computer just as if it were another drive on your PC. Just copy and paste the file as if you were making a copy on your hard drive. (There is a bug in some versions of Windows Explorer where, after you make a connection, it shows a blank directory. You can fix this by putting the focus back in the address bar and hitting the enter key without changing the address.)

Comment: Sorry I believe I worded my question poorly, I believe what I meant to ask was how to copy a file from windows to the linux computer I am connected to?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include instructions for copying from Windows to a linux computer.

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY itself isn't a file transfer program.  It gives you access to the remote computer, but you won't see any of your files there.

However, PuTTY includes two file transfer programs called PSCP and PSFTP.  You probably need to use those.  Basic usage, from a command prompt on your Windows PC:

```
pscp myfile username@hostname:~/
```

Comment: Sorry I believe I worded my question poorly, I believe what I meant to ask was how to copy a file from windows to the linux computer I am connected to?

Comment: Like he said. It's a command line for in Windows to transfer a local file over to Linux.